# Preview files with Python / Django

Tags: python, django, file, preview

Is there a way to preview files (like .doc, .docx, .png, .jpg, .pdf) in the browser without using Google or microsoft URLs?

Searching on google I can not find a solution that fits in this case. I can not use cloud solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to view PDFs. The rest, you could try converting to PDF. This is what Document Management System solutions like [Nuxeo](https://www.nuxeo.com) do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do it purely via python, you can use libs for each respective format like [pdf2html](https://github.com/mgedmin/pdf2html) and [docx2html](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx2html) etc, but the best way to do this is to use a frontend utility or framework because the python equivalents are relatively buggy and will slow down your app since they often rely on things like libxml.